# RoR: Saving form data into two database tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a form where user inputs their information. But I'd like to also save one of the input field data into another table.

I have `User` table and `Business` table

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  ... some input fields
  <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  ... more input fields
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller is like this:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @biz = Business.find_or_create_by_name(params[:company_name])
  @biz.save
end
```

Its saving the data in the User's table, but its not saving data into the Business table.

Comment: are there any validations in Business model?

Comment: @tihom not at this moment. I'd like to set one up though

Comment: Have you tried `Business.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:company_name])`?

Comment: @vinodadhikary I get `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`? Know why I would get this?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  Rails likes it when `edit` shows the form and `update` handles the PUT (and the updating attributes).  If you do this, your methods will look like this.

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
end 

def update
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
end
```

I'd also put the logic to create the business in user model if a company name is submitted with the user params.

in User.rb

```
validates_length_of :business_name, :minimum => 2, :allow_blank => true

attr_accessor :business_name

before_validation :ensure_business

def ensure_business
  if business_name.present?
    b = Business.where(:name => business_name).first_or_create
    self.business_id = b.id
  end
end
```

Comment: This method looks like it might work, but am I supposed to put the method `ensure_business` somewhere to call it? or does rails go through `before_validation` and calls the method before saving automatically?

Comment: Put it in user.rb.  It'll be called when you try to save the user.  It may be a before_save - it depends on the business logic of your user and business objects.

Comment: I have put it in my model, but its not saving to my business table. Am I missing something from this?

Comment: Are there any validations on your Business model?

Comment: No, there are currently no validations, is that why its not working?

Comment: No - That may have been why it wasn't creating a business.  Do this - take a look at the 'b' object and inspect it (you can `raise b.inspect` right after it's created) and see what it looks like.